# Fetching emails from database don't fetch if cell is null empty

Tags: php, mysql

I write  a code to fetch emails of all users and then save them in a txt file but some users don't have and email  because they registered using phone number
so when i am trying to fetch
it dump in txt file like 
http://prntscr.com/5wf7cv

I want if cell is empty/NULL  don't fetch anything 
Anyone can help me to Fix it?

```
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  "); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

 $email = $row['email']   ;

  $fp = fopen("emaillist.txt", "a");
$savestring = "\n$email";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
}
echo  "DONE ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM user  WHERE email != NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user  "); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {


    if (strlen($row['email'] ) > 0){
        $email = $row['email'];
        $fp = fopen("emaillist.txt", "a");
        $savestring = "\n$email";
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
echo  "DONE ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user  WHERE email IS NOT NULL
```

The only way to check on NULL values is

`column IS NULL` or `column IS NOT NULL`